# Text Combination Generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

file1.txt

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
```

file2.txt

```
f1
f2
```

file3.txt | output

```
item1-f1
item2-f1
item3-f1
item4-f1
item5-f1
item6-f2
item7-f2
item8-f2
item9-f2
item10-f2
```

List are strings. Basically for each 5 from file1, 1 from file2 will add as I showed at output.

Comment: Can you please show us where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    l1=f.readlines()

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    l2=f.readlines()

l2[-1]=l2[-1]+'\n'

l2=sum([[i]*5 for i in l2], [])

l3=[i.replace('\n', '')+'-'+k for i,k in zip(l1,l2)]

with open('file3.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(l3)
```

Comment: Should we ask what's he'd tried and show us the effort first -before giving answer?  (otherwise it's a good post)

Comment: Sure, however it doesn't look as a homework, rather like a real problem, that's why i chose to help

Comment: I stuck at the end with string. it was considering as int